# issue in using dynamic grid link button for scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl (control) as this has to be declared at page_load

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, export-to-csv

I was trying to download csv file on grid's dynamically created link button.
I was facing issue while downloading csv in asp.net.
Exception : Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException
This Exception is resolved by using code:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.grouplnkbutton);
```

at page_load event,but this.grouplnkbutton (dynamically created link button i.e. grouplnkbutton control is not available at page_load event).

how can i use linkbutton with scriptmanager at page_load event.

Code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.grouplnkbutton);
        //codes
     }

 protected void hlGroupName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try`enter code here`
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            grouplnkbutton = sender as LinkButton;
            string linkBtnValue = grouplnkbutton.CommandArgument;
            GridDataItem item = grouplnkbutton.NamingContainer as GridDataItem;
            ExportToCSV exportToCSV = new ExportToCSV();
            StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

            DataSet gridData = new DataSet();

            int scheduleId = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("hidID")).Value);
            csv = exportToCSV.ExportScheduleDataToCSV(scheduleId);

            Response.Buffer = true;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=perfscheduleReport.csv");
            //Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Output.Write(csv.ToString());
            //Response.Write(csv.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            //Response.End();

        }
```

Thanks for solution.
markup code

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="PerfGrid" GridLines="None" runat="server" CssClass="BorderGrid" OnItemDataBound="PerfGrid_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand ="PerfGrid_ItemCommand"
                                                                                    Skin="Default" Width="100%" PageSize="100" PagerStyle-PageSizeLabelText="Records Per Page" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" OnNeedDataSource="PerfGrid_NeedDataSource" OnPageIndexChanged="PerfGrid_PageIndexChanged">

                                                                                    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
                                                                                        <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" AllowRowResize="false" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="false"
                                                                                            ClipCellContentOnResize="true" EnableRealTimeResize="false" AllowResizeToFit="true" />
                                                                                    </ClientSettings>
                                                                                    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="True">

                                                                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" Font-Bold="true"></HeaderStyle>
                                                                                        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="text2" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                                        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#E6EEF8" CssClass="text2" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                                        <%--<PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />--%>
                                                                                        <Columns>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ScheduleId" Display="false" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="ID" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10px">
                                                                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-Width="15px" AllowFiltering="false">
                                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSelect" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="GroupingName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Group Name" SortExpression="GroupName" HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                                                                                                  <ItemTemplate>

                                                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="hlGroupName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupingName") %>' OnClick="hlGroupName_Click"></asp:LinkButton>  <%--CommandName="Export"--%>

                                                                                            <%--<asp:HyperLink ID="hlTestCase" CommandName="Edit1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("TestDescription") %>'--%>
                                                                                                Target="_self"></asp:HyperLink>--%>
                                                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidID" runat="server" Value='<%# CheckNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScheduleId") , false)%>' />
                                                                                              <%--Value='<%# Container.DataItem("Id") %>' Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>--%>
                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="TestDescription" DataField="TestDescription" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Test Cases" HeaderStyle-Width="30px">
                                                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="ServerIP" DataField="ServerIP" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Server IP" HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                                                                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="LoadNoOfUsersTobeSimulated" DataField="LoadNoOfUsersTobeSimulated" HeaderText="Users Load" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="12px">
                                                                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="StartTime" DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="25px">
                                                                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="EndTime" DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="End Time" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="25px">
                                                                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                                        </Columns>
                                                                                    </MasterTableView>
                                                                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

in this lnkbtn - ID -"hlGroupname" onclick event i want to downalod csv
But getting Exception:Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException
resolved Exception using :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.PerfGrid);
//codes
}
```

I am using Scriptmanager as my grid is under updatepanel.
Here PerfGrid is telerikGrid control. Instead of grid control i want to use dynamically created grid link button. And onclick event of lnkbutton i want to download csv.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, your code looks fine, but why the need for the register script?

dump that code you have in the load event, I don't see a need for it??

You not posted your markup, but say a grid like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="ProjectName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectDate" HeaderText="ProjectDate"  />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">My Link</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Your button code then as you have looks fine.

I don't (so far) on what you posted see why any need for register script or that button event needs that code. You can just wire up the click event as you have, nothing more need be done.

So, in above, the linkbutton should be just fine. Check and REMOVE the post-back URL setting for that link button - that might be your issue (but, you not posted at least the markup you have for the LinkButton.

It should only require the click even code you have - no other settings such as post-back URL is required for that button click event to work. In fact, it not at all clear why you using a LinkButton as opposed to say a button? (I see no need for a link button ).

So, no real reason for the register script stuff - remove it.

And note how I don't have to include the PK row "ID" in the markup, or even a hidden field. The datakeys setting is just for that reason (and it nice from a secuirty point of view - I don't have to render the PK row ID has hiddefield or anything.

Hence this code can get the PK id

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lBtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gRow = lBtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        // get row click index with gRow.RowIndex
        int? pkID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;
```

And my code to fill the gv was this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Project"L, conn))
{
conn.Open();

GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Now, of course if you using the row data bound for ANY thing at all? Then don't bind the GV to the reader, but use this:

```
conn.Open();
DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
GridView1.DataBind();
```